# Ansible define variable if match in regex

Tags: ansible, variable-assignment

I have an extra variable in my command to execute the Ansible playbook.
I would like to assign another variable only if the extra variable has the prefix `database + "/"`

For example:

```
ansible-playbook ./test.yml -e "branch=database/1.3.4"
```

The variable(branch) has prefix `database + "/"` I would like to assign one more variable(version) as 1.3.4

```
  tasks:
  - name: Extract Version Number
    ansible.builtin.set_fact:
      version: "V{{ branch.split('/')[1] }}"
    when: "{{ branch | regex_search('release/') }}"
```

But I received this error message:

```
FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check '{{ branch | regex_search('database/') }}' failed.
```

I am very new to Ansible, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do something like this:

```
  tasks:
    - name: setfact
      set_fact:
        version: "V{{ branch.split('/')[1] }}"
      when: branch | d('') | regex_search('database/')
    
    - debug:  
        msg: "{{ version if version is defined else 'nothing'}} - {{branch | d('') }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Q: ***Assign another variable only if the variable has the prefix 'database + /'***

A: If you want to use the [*regex_search*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#searching-strings-with-regular-expressions) filter to test the condition start searching from the beginning of the string. Note the '^' character in the regex. For example,

```yaml
    - debug:
        var: branch
    - set_fact:
        version: "{{ branch.split('/')[1] }}"
      when: branch|regex_search('^database/')
    - debug:
        var: version
```

*regex_search* returns an empty string if it cannot find a match. This works as expected because, in a condition, an empty string evaluates to *False* and any non-empty string evaluates to *True*

```yaml
  branch: database/1.3.4
  version: 1.3.4
```

If you omit the leading '^' the filter will return any match in the string. This is not what you want. For example,

```yaml
   - debug:
        var: branch
    - set_fact:
        version: "{{ branch.split('/')[1] }}"
      when: branch|regex_search('database/')
    - debug:
        var: version
```

*regex_search* matches the regex also behind the prefix 'sql-'

```yaml
  branch: sql-database/1.3.4
  version: 1.3.4
```

---

But, instead of using the filter *regex_search*, you might want to simply compare the strings. For example, the task below also gives what you want

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        version: "{{ arr.1|d('undef') }}"
      when: arr.0 == 'database'
      vars:
        arr: "{{ branch|d('undef')|split('/') }}"
```

If you need more complex conditions see [Testing strings](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings).